# Laravel 5.5 belongsTo not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have three models with a relation, `ReservedTicket` extends `Ticket`:

`App/TicketType`:

```
class TicketType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'countinuous', 'price', 'description', 'personal', 'total', 'minage', 'maxage', 'event_id', 'header_image_path', 'footer_image_path',
    ];

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`App/Ticket`:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'prefix_name', 'ticket_type_id', 'sold_on', 'sold_by', 'scanned_at', 'scanned_by',
    ];

    public function ticketType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TicketType::class, 'ticket_type_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`App/ReservedTicket`:

```
class ReservedTicket extends Ticket
{
    protected $table = 'reserved_tickets';
}
```

I have set up the relations like I did on any other model in my application. I even tried specifying the foreign key column, but it's not happening.

I do get all `Tickets` if I use go through the `hasMany()` of `TicketType`. But the other way around it doesn't work.

Am I missing something because of the inheritance? I'm using an instance of `ReservedTicket`.

Comment: I think extending the ticket you will need to define the relationship in the reservedTicket class as well

Comment: This looks like a bad way of doing things. You have 2 tables with identical columns that store almost identical entities (tickets). In addition you seem to be relating the `ticket_type` table with either/both of them.

Comment: @apokryfos Saving the tickets in several (3 actually) tables is because of the large dataset they will be containing and to prevent for doubles sales in case of a lot of traffic.

Comment: The DBMS has tools to sort these things out for you. You're just making your life harder

Comment: This way the tables could be moved to a dedicated MySQL server if they exceed a certain size...

Comment: @happymacarts I tried that and after hunting down a typo, It worked. Thank you. If you put as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Extending a class to a new model you will need to define the relations in the extended class as well

```
class ReservedTicket extends Ticket
{
    protected $table = 'reserved_tickets';

    public function ticketType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TicketType::class, 'ticket_type_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: It extends Ticket so the methods shouldn't need re-defining.

Comment: @devon yes, but he is referencing a different table name so that relationship needs to be made as well (if that makes sense). the inherited "$this" is the Ticket Table

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with Reflection then?  $this->table would be 'reserved_tickets' from any inherited methods.  An example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24300f8005774a2cb0d659e6f16c2dbc97c48e0d

Comment: @Devon But `ReservedTicket` is inheriting from `Ticket`